# SSIS source and destination components

Tags: ssis

From the Data Flow Task below, which control can i use to get the rows in Merge Join 1 into Merge Join 2 such that i can do another Merge Join with data coming coming from OLE DB Source 1 at Merge Join 2.

[image]

Comment: Sort both outputs by some column(s) from both Merge joins and then insert 3rd Merge join...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly but probably multicast will help you, something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You havent described this very well, but "get the rows in ... into ..." possibly implies a Union All transformation?